Chrome takes up unproportioned memory in web app
I have a web app I am developing using Angular 14, and I've had windows task manager open while I was using it.
I've noticed the memory that chrome is using is somewhere around 1.5GB (with only my app's tab open).
I've decided to search for the cause, and took a heap snapshot and it was only 70MB.
So that really confused me, why would Chrome take up so much memory if the entire JS memory heap is only 70MB?
I've tried to play around with my app and noticed exactly where this happens. On one of the pages in my app there is sort of timeline map where I render many small squares (1000's) representing events. I render the map and the squares with d3.js. When this map grows I can see Chrome's memory exploding all the way to 2GB, while the memory heap is still very low around 70MB.
There is another thing I've noticed while trying to understand the cause of this. In Chrome's Task Manager there is a row for "GPU Process" which is also taking about 700MB, while my app was taking around 600MB. So I found a way to disable the "GPU Process" and that certainly reduced the amount of memory being used by Chrome, but was still very high around 600MB.
I've tried running my app on another machine, and I've tried running my app on Edge instead of Chrome, I still notice the same behavior.

Has anyone encountered something like this?
Why is this happening?
Could this be caused by d3.js?
Can I do something to reduce the amount of memory being used by Chrome, or is this out of my reach as a developer and it has to do with how Chrome works?
Can and should I disable the "GPU Process" programmatically?


How big are these “small squares”? 1.5GB is a lot but it sounds like it’s mostly texture memory, which would make sense if you’re rendering thousands of little images. Consider that a 128x128 color image is 50KB; 30000 such images would occupy 1.5GB of memory.

@nneonneo
They are not images.
I render them with d3.js, they are small 3x3 pixel squares in a single color each time. Usually no more than 5000 squares at max.
What do you mean by "texture memory"?

Are all these squares visible on the page at the same time? Is there a way to selectively turn things off when not on-screen to preserve memory? Or some other sort of way to cache unchanging elements?

@EricKrief texture memory refers to the memory which is used to store images for rendering. Often, images that have to be immediately rendered will sit in both main memory and in the GPU memory. Sometimes, you can optimize the use of this texture memory by defining a single large image rather than large numbers of small ones - for example, a single 210x210 image can be used to pack 4900 3x3 images with far less overhead. This is referred to as a texture atlas.

@NickFelker Yes they are all visible at the same time, unless we zoom in on a particular part but mostly it will be zoomed out and everything will be visible. The elements don't change, all that happens is that more elements are added gradually with time. I guess trying to figure out if I can find a way to only render part of them could be a solid approach.

@nneonneo This concept is new to me. I am used to thinking of performance in CPU and memory terms, never thought of GPU memory when talking about performance.
Trying to make one single image to render sounds like an interesting option I might look into.
So when I see the overall memory taken in Task Manager, this includes the GPU memory as well as the "regular" memory of the system?
